# How to create Spacemacs key binding starting with `SPC`?

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs

I'm trying to add a key binding by doing the following:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "SPC-;") 'spacemacs/default-pop-shell)
```

but it gets interpreted as the separate keys S, P, etc and produces the error:

```
global-set-key: Key sequence S P C - ; starts with non-prefix key S
```

What is the correct way to map something starting with SPC?

I'm not sure if any of this is specific to Spacemacs, but that's the distro I'm using.

Answer (score 4):

The answer was posted by @duianto on the [Spacemacs gitter](https://gitter.im/syl20bnr/spacemacs?at=5a466760b48e8c35667b664f):

```
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys (kbd ";") 'spacemacs/default-pop-shell)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
(kbd "<SPC> ;")
```

Comment: That produces the same error, but now it says that the key sequence starts with non-prefix key `SPC` instead of `S`.

Comment: Ah, I see. The original post contained two problems. One (which I solved) was the syntax of `kbd`. The other that space isn't a prefix key (which I assumed it was).

Comment: Yes, sorry about the confusion. Thank you for teaching me how to use `kbd` with `<SPC>` :)